# can we use RJ45 with cat7 sftp?

Tags: ethernet, cable

I am currently working on connecting ip cameras together .
I am using cat7 sftp cable .

according to the bellow article :

http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-rj45-and-rj48/

I understand that :

1. RJ45 is used with UTP cable only .
2. I can't use RJ48 because it will not fit into my NVR and SWITCHES .

I have two questions :

1. I found RJ45 which fit cat7 cable .

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071GXPTVZ/ref=twister_B09ZYBKJFZ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071GXPTVZ)

How could that happen ? RJ45 should be used with utp cables only ? right ?

2. what's the right connector to choose to connect cat7 sftp to ip camera ?

some people suggest to connect Cat6a Cat7 Keystone at the end of cat7 cable .

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B074PKQ1S1/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074PKQ1S1)

then to use short cat 6 cable to connect between the keystone and ip camera .

is that the correct method ?

Thank you

Comment: Remember that the horizontal cabling (in the ceiling and wall) needs to be solid-core cable that terminates in wall sockets and the back of patch panels, while the patch cables that connect the devices to the wall socket is stranded cable. You are allowed up to 90 meters of solid-core, and up to 10 meters of stranded (total 100 meters). Also, you must use a proper cable tester (several thousand $) to certify the cabling. You really want a certified installer to do it because you can permanently ruin the cabling (breaking the contiguous shield or untwisting too much).

Comment: I do not mean to be patronizing, but if you need to ask this question, you do not have the skills to install the cabling to meet the required test suite to pass certification. Your company needs to hire a certified installer. Network cabling is not like telephone cabling where simple electrical connectivity is sufficient. Modern network frequencies require tight specifications to be met, and it requires an experienced installer and post-installation testing with the proper (expensive) test equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we use RJ45 with cat7 sftp?

Yes, you can and there's no alternative[*1]. What is commonly called "RJ45" is technically a 8P8C modular connector, officially specified as IEC 60603-7. The RJ48 pinout (pairs 1-2 and 4-5) is not usable for Ethernet networking at all - you need all pairs (1-2, 3-6, 4-5, 7-8) for 1000BASE-T and faster. 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX also work with the 1-2 and 3-6 pairs only, but "Cat x" implies full four-pair/eight-wire cabling.

Horizontal, solid-core cable is generally terminated in a jack or a panel. The jack/panel specifications need to match the category you want to achieve. However, Cat 6/6A/7 deployment is not trivial at all. It should only be done by a professional installer and certified before use. Keystone connectors are easy to use but not likely to meet the specifications.

[*1] As Jörg has correctly pointed out: proper, on-topic deployment of **category 7 cabling requires TERA or GG45 termination** as per ISO 11801 (cat 7 is not recognized by TIA/EIA). Terminating cat 7 cabling with shielded 8P8C does not necessarily support 10GBASE-T. As the question is asked I was assuming that only 1000BASE-T (or less) would be used, with cat 7 instead of cat 5e cabling as a future reserve (I've seen that a lot) - but that may not be the case here.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand that I can use RJ45 with cat7 sftp . but why in the article mentioned : RJ45 IS CONNECTED WITH UTP CABLE WHILE RJ48 USES STP .

Comment: I don't see your problem - "RJ45" aka 8P8C come in shielded and unshielded variants. Cat 7 uses shielding, so you need a shielded panel / connector. If you want to use unshielded cabling you should check out Cat 6A (or much simpler Cat 5e if you're never going to need more than 1 Gbit/s).

Comment: I was under the impression that Cat7 is only specified for TERA and GG45, and does not allow the use of RJ45.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, that's correct - I was bluntly assuming that only 1000BASE-T would be used due to the mention of IP cameras... Thx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

RJ45 and RJ48 use the same physical connector. The difference is in how the pairs are used. RJ48 uses [1, 2], [4, 5]; this is typically the case for 4-wire T1 interfaces. RJ45 uses [1, 2], [3, 6]; this is typically the case for ethernet. You can shield either one.

It should be noted, if you run all four pairs, it doesn't matter... [1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5], [7, 8]

(And there are various designations for "shield" as well. full cable shielding, per pair shielding, etc.)